# ember-simple-auth with ember-cli

Tags: authentication, ember.js, ember-cli

Trying to follow the instructions for using ember-simple-auth with ember-cli here:

http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/

At the start it says to do :

> ```
> npm install --save-dev ember-cli-simple-auth
> ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth
> ```

But as soon as I try that 'ember generate' I get the following error:

```
The `ember generate` command requires an entity name to be specified. For more details, use `ember help`.
```

So it looks like that ember generate command isn't right... anyone able to help?
Am I to generate an initialiser or something?

Thanks

Comment: What version of ember-cli are you using?

Comment: Add `ember -v` output.

Comment: The output from the ember version command is:
version: 0.0.40
node: 0.10.24
npm: 1.4.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things were needed to sort this out.

**Firstly** to upgrade the version of ember-cli

This is covered here:

http://www.ember-cli.com/#upgrading-an-ember-cli-app

Use NPM to update to the latest released version of Ember CLI.

> npm install --save-dev ember-cli

When you update to the latest version you may need to re-install files from the app blueprint and update Node NPM dependencies.

> ember init

This will re-copy files from the project blueprint. You can choose to overwrite existing files or not. It will subsequently call npm install to update any changed dependencies.

And **Secondly**, needed to find the updated blog instructions for ember-simple-auth:

http://log.simplabs.com/post/90339547725/using-ember-simple-auth-with-ember-cli

which don't include the generate command now.

Comment: I updated the blog post to include the new generator step: http://log.simplabs.com/post/90339547725/using-ember-simple-auth-with-ember-cli

Comment: Worth noting that you can now use ember-cli-update to upgrade Ember, ember-cli, and other dependencies! https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-update

Answer (score 0):

Typically the blueprints the generators use, require the following syntax:
`ember generate <blueprint> <name>`

I would expect the usage of simple-auth to follow the convention and you would do something like

```
ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth <your new route name>
```

Comment: The Ember Simple Auth generator is just `ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth`. The problem is most likely that the OP is using an older Ember CLI version.

Comment: I appear to be using 0.0.40 
Would this be too old?

Comment: I would try upgrading considering the latest is 0.1.0 (really says 0.1.1 once installed)

Answer (score 0):

Ember simple auth and ember cli simple auth are two slightly different things. On the ember simple auth page https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#ember-cli it says

> If you're using Ember CLI, just add the ember-cli-simple-auth Ember
>   CLI Addon to your project and Ember Simple Auth will setup itself.

which means to do what you are doing you need the ember-cli-simple-auth add on - found here 
https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth

The way to install that is how youve described above.

Ember simple auth has gone through a lot of changes in its time so the page you are getting your instructions from might not be the most up to date. Github is usually the best place to check for solutions to packages if you are having difficulties as the most up to date documentation will most liekly be there.

Comment: Thanks Craicerjack, the upgrading of my ember-cli to 0.1.1 allowed the second command, the 'ember generate ember-cli-simple-auth' one, to work. But funnily enough the latest blog post to do with simple-auth doesn't feature that generate command now... So its hard to know if the github page is right or the blog post.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. Gald you got it sorted

Comment: Ember Simple Auth maintainer here - in general github is always up to date while the blog posts outdate over time